# How to reduce the pointer/address width in a hash table slot?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, hash

Assume that we have a hash table using chaining (linked list) to resove hash collisions. Each hash table slot will have a pointer field pointing to the first node of the linked list. This pointer will occupy 4 or 8 bytes depending on the x86 or x64 OS.

For some large hash table with million slots, the pointers will consume huge memory resource. For a hardware implementation, we can customize the pointer/address width on the FPGA to save memory. My question is, for a software  implementation, is there any way also to reduce the pointer size to, say, 3 bytes?

Comment: If your hash table has the capacity for quote: "million slots", you cannot reduce to 2 bytes (2^16 -> 65536)...

Comment: What you could do is to implement a hash table which has no external overflow lists but some overflow-re-hashing strategy, in place.

Comment: Have an overflow table. Entries of the table (if not NULL) point to each overflow linked list. Store the table index in the hash entry rather than the pointer directly.

Comment: the best solution for one million entries requires already one million values so that's already more like 3 bytes. With 4 bytes you should be fine but in this case you're only winning on a 64-bit system (which by the way usually address on only 40 bits anyway)

Comment: Used the wrong term - sorry. Did not mean re-hashing which is used for another purpose but "double hashing". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing

Comment: Could you preallocate the memory as an array of million slots, where each hash table slot contains an index into an preallocated array of nodes, where each node contains a index to the "next" node or a -1 to indicate the end of a "list"? The array of nodes would be initialized as a single "empty" list, to be used as a free pool of nodes.

Comment: Instead of a hash table with linked-list buckets why not a hash table with vector buckets?

Comment: Galik: that only improves the situation for buckets into which two or more elements collide... possible still useful, but only fixes a small fraction of the waste (exact amount depends on load factor, hash quality vs. key grouping etc., but perhaps ~1/5th).

Comment: @Bloodmoon: what's optimal depends somewhat on your element size(s)... what is it?  E.g. if it's say `char` using closed hashing / open addressing is very appealling, whereas if you're storing 64 byte elements a better hash table layout isn't going to reduce memory usage by more than ~20% vs. `unordered_map`.

Comment: @AlanAu could you please elaborate on "store the table index rather than the pointer"?

Comment: @TonyD How is unordered_map implemented? Open addressing or open hashing?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the pointer size overhead for your overflow lists to 0 bytes if you do not implement the hash table that way in the first place.

There is actually no drawback in implementing hash tables such that if one slot of the table already holds a value, you apply "some strategy" to find another, empty slot. If you did so while writing, your read function needs to execute analog steps to find the right spot to read from.

This approach actually does not perform worse than external overflow lists, because what you do in case of having those overflow lists is to perform a linear search within the overflow list. With an in-place hash table you perform - depending on the chosen strategy also something like a linear probing.

One idea to do that is to have a set of hash keys instead of one. (Typically 2, then it is called Double hashing). If you write and the slot of the table is already taken, you use the next hash key in your set and try again, until your hash keys are exhausted or until you found an empty spot. With N hash keys, you do N steps.

For reading, in that case, you try to find the entry, applying the set of hash keys in the same sequence as you did for write and probe if this is the entry you need, just the same way as you would probe your overflow lists.

Since hash tables only "make sense" if they have a low fill rate, this strategy actually saves much of the memory which would be needed for an overflow-list implementation.

Comment: There's a mix of good information and suspect generalisation in there.  "no drawback" is wrong - implementing erase involves either having a sentinel or secondary variable to marking buckets "deleted" and having to skip over that element during searches, or re-compacting one of the collision chains passing through the bucket (which is often impractical), and worst case collisions can be much worse than open hashing because the same bucket might be visited many times during a search, or less-random approaches like the linear probing you mention lead to areas of the table being full.

Comment: "Since hash tables only "make sense" if they have a low fill rate," - with open hashing the load factor can exceed 1 without dramatic consequences, and even close hashing with a good hash function and collision handing can comfortably handing around .8 to .9.  I would call that "low".  *"...this strategy actually saves much of the memory which would be needed for an overflow-list implementation."* - whether it saves memory depends mainly on the element size, as you're embracing more unusued element-sized buckets for less pointers.

Comment: True. No drawbacks is an over statements. But if it is a cheaper or a more expensive drawback compared to open hashing always can be asked. Having a (singly linked  or alike) list implies heap operations, taking the heap mutex, compromises locality just as multi-hashing does. So as usual it is a consideration of trade offs. In case of a bad hash key, the open hashing degenerates to a linear list which is no less inconvenient. I felt urged to demonstrate that open hashing is not the only way and I even think that it is the least commonly used way to implement hash tables.

Comment: As for "nearly full" hash tables (0.9 etc.) I am tempted to think it is rather some bucket search than a  hash table in its true sense. Probably it would be time to switch to another data structure altogether in that case.

Comment: *"degenerates to a linear list which is no less inconvenient"* - actually it can be, as at least you're only comparing the key with each element in that list once... with some collision-handling approaches used for closed hashing, you can end up comparing the key against the same elements many, many times before you eventually hit an empty bucket or match.  There are ways to avoid that though (e.g. quadratic probing with a prime number of buckets).  Still, I absolutely agree that closed hashing is very, very useful in many situations.

Comment: Re "nearly full" - it's all tuning... less memory use / better caching vs. more collisions.  When I worked at a huge financial data provider, the primary hash tables for mapping instrument ids on incoming tick data to those instruments' header & tick streams was kept at 80-90% utilisation using close hashing... was optimal.

Comment: So insert operation takes longer in the worst case but you save the heap operations and all the other overheads - you pay a price in any case. And how many probes can one do in the time worth one memory allocation, probably with some new paging in etc.? . If that is acceptable or not depends on the needs of the application. The strategy chosen to find new slots has an impact on locality. The overflow list approach, in contrast has inherently a bad locality.

Comment: Taking a step back, I just wanted to point out that you were painting an inapprpropriately one-sided picture with a couple points in the answer.  There are certainly pros and cons, and as with most performance issues anyone who cares should try both and measure with their own data and systems.  Definitely it's good to have an answer suggest closed hashing to encourage the OP to do so.

Comment: @user2225104 thanks for your answer. The element size in my case is large than 8 bytes, or can be even more. So closed hashing/open addressing seems not an appealing method for memory savings. In the open hashing/linked list method for my case, the linked list of non-empty slot has a length of at most 2, most of them has only one node. The bulk of the slots are empty.